# Properties of Infinite Limits

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Could somebody please show how $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n = 0$$ I always think that considering $|x|>1$ as $n$ becomes larger, $x^n$ also becomes larger. In this case,$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n = \infty$$ Could somebody please explain where I've gone wrong?

Thanks very much!

Comment: It certainly depends on what $x$ is, doesn't it?

Comment: Is $x$ larger or smaller than $1$? Positive or negative?

Comment: As far as I can understand, if $|x|<1$, then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n = 0$$ If $|x|>1$, then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n = \infty$$

Comment: @BetterWorld: If $x > 1$ then $x^{n} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. When $x < -1$ then the limit $x^{n}$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly not true always.

It is only true when $|x|\lt 1$, otherwise, it will go to infinity as you said.

Unless x=1, then it will just stay as 1 , as pointed out below.

Ie,

$\lim_{n \to \infty}x^n= 0$ if $|x| \lt 1$

$\lim_{n \to \infty}x^n= 1$ if $x=1$

$\lim_{n \to \infty}x^n= \infty$ if $|x| \gt 1$

Comment: Not if $|x|=1$ :)

Comment: @avid19 yes of course :)

Comment: No its divergent in that case